# CarouselView Xamarin forms indicator view not showing

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, carousel, landscape

Im trying to see the indicator views , but for some reason I cant see them , also , I tried horizontals options : fill and expand , it does work on ios on landscaping orientation.However, I cant get it to expand when the android is on landscape

this is what I have

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
   <CarouselView EmptyView="No items to display."  IndicatorView="indicatorView" ItemsSource="{Binding CarouselImages}">
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" >
                 <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"
                               Aspect="AspectFill"
                               HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
              </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
     <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView"
                    IndicatorsShape="Square"
                     MaximumVisible="6"
                   IndicatorColor="DarkRed"
                   SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkGray"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" />

     </StackLayout>
```

Comment: try please adding height request for the indicator

Comment: Any update on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a `size` , for example `IndicatorSize="12"`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/indicatorview#change-indicator-size

```
  <IndicatorView
            x:Name="indicatorView"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            IndicatorColor="DarkRed"
            IndicatorsShape="Square"
            MaximumVisible="6"
            IndicatorSize="12"
            SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkGray" />
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just manage to **set** the `VerticalOptions` and `HorizontalOptions`  of the indicatorView to `FillAndExpand` like below:

```
<IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView"
                   IndicatorsShape="Square"
                   MaximumVisible="6"
                   IndicatorColor="DarkRed"
                   SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkGray"
                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   />
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, Indicator view is actually displayed. You haven't noticed it since it's present at the bottom edge of the mobile screen. Please refer the screenshot below:

[Indicator view present at the bottom edge of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLQ8Q.png).

This is happening because the carousel view expands to most of the screen size available.
You can fix this issue by providing a Heightrequest to carouselview control, say 200.

For example:

```
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <CarouselView EmptyView="No items to display." HeightRequest="200"  VerticalOptions="Center" IndicatorView="indicatorView" ItemsSource="{Binding CarouselImages}">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
        <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView"
                IndicatorsShape="Square"
                 MaximumVisible="6"
               IndicatorColor="DarkRed"
               SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkGray"
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />

    </StackLayout>
```

Please refer the screenshot after providing HeightRequest to the carouselview control:

[Screenshot after adding HeightRequest to the carousel control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAt90.png)